# Disabling the scroll ability in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, css, tablesorter, jsfiddle

Is there a way to fully disable scrolling in JSFiddle.

I've tried:

```
position: fixed;
```

and

```
overflow: hidden;
```

however I can still scrolldown when I embed the results in my site. I wondered if anyone had any tips on how to fully fix something and have no scrolling abilities.

My current HTML and CSS:

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: collapse;
}
html,
body {
  height: fit;
  background: #e2dede;
  margin: 10px;
}
div {
  width: fit;
  overflow: hidden;
}
td + td {
  border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}
th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #333333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-family: "raleway";
  font-size: 14px;
}
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  background: #e2dede;
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-family: "raleway";
  font-size: 13px
}
```

```html
<table class="tablesorter">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Release Date</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Peter Parker</td>
        <td>11/07/2015</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John Hood</td>
        <td>11/07/2015</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Clark Kent</td>
        <td>12/07/2015</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bruce Almighty</td>
        <td>13/07/2015</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bruce Evans</td>
        <td>14/07/2015</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Why are yuo embedding jsfiddle on your site?

Comment: As I have created tablesorters for my website on there

Comment: I don't fully understand your question (the embeding part), but if you want to remove scrolling from the `result frame` from fiddlejs, you will need to get the reference to that `iframe` and add an attribute `scrolling='no'`

Comment: I add the results to my page via a html and inserting the /show url. Is there an easier way of getting the fiddle you have created to your website?

Answer (score 1):

When you embed a JSFiddle demo on your site, JSFiddle adds a "Result" bar across the top to add a link to allow editing the demo in JSFiddle. Because of that bar and a nested iframe set to the same height as the outer frame, a scroll bar shows up ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5sadgev6/embedded/result/)).

```
<iframe height="300" width="100%" src="http://jsfiddle.net/5sadgev6/embedded/result,html,css" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0">

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="head">
      <h1><a title="Edit in JSFiddle" href="/5sadgev6/light/" target="new">Edit in JSFiddle</a></h1>
      <div id="actions" class="">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs" style="height: 298px;">
      <div class="tCont result active" id="result">
        <iframe style="height: 300px;" src="//fiddle.jshell.net/5sadgev6/show/light/" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-scripts allow-same-origin"></iframe>
      </div>

      ...

    </div>
  </div>

</iframe>
```

Look at the height settings added by JSFiddle in the above HTML.

So essentially, you can't prevent the embedded JSFiddle iframe from scrolling since it's the iframe within the embedded iframe that has a set height.

If you don't like the scroll:

- Submit an issue to jsfiddle: https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues
- Don't use an embedded jsFiddle on your site.
- Make a [Stylish](https://github.com/JasonBarnabe/stylish) style that sets the iframe embedded within the iframe height to auto - this would only work on your browser, but would apply to the sites you specify.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks Mottie. I seem to be pulling my hair out at the moment over this and JSFiddle as I am a newbie to this. What is the best way then of getting a fiddle you create on jsfiddle on to a site?

Comment: Why are you using a fiddle? Do you want your users to be able to edit it? Or are you just showing a demo? Either way, share a link to the jsFiddle demo and make an iframe pointing to a page you host with the demo - then you have total control over the demo.

Comment: I created the table on JSFiddle and now do not know how to remove the HTML, JS and CSS code from there on to my Wix.com created website. How do I add the coding into iFrame without it being a demo or editble?

Comment: I've never used Wix.com... if they allow you to create a new page, then copy the HTML, CSS & javascript (make sure the code is wrapped in a document ready function) into that new page. Then add an iframe which points to that new page. If you need help with that, please contact the Wix.com support staff.